# Correlation Matrix (kind of) in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a set of categorical variables coded as one-hot format.
Im trying to make something like a correlation matrix, but calculating the times every pair of variables is "on" together (meaning sum every case the two variables are 1)
I know i can calculate that by just multiplying both vectors and then sum the total (as only the times when both are 1 will add to the sum)
But i cant think of a way to make the final matrix.
For example
I have this dataset

```
 A B C D E
 1 1 0 1 0
 0 1 0 0 1
 0 0 1 1 1
 0 0 1 0 1
 0 0 0 0 1
```

i need a matrix like this (the diagonal values doesnt really matter)

```
  A B C D E
A - 1 0 1 0
B 1 - 0 1 0
C 0 0 - 1 2
D 1 1 1 - 1
E 0 0 2 1 -
```

Notice for example that E-C is 2 because in 2 ocations both were On (1)

Comment: Isn't this just matrix multiplication? `t(x) %*% x`

Comment: it is indeed! It was as easy as calculating the cross product of the matrix. I guess my linear algebra teachers would be disappointed. Thanks!